# Android custom context menu

Tags: android, contextmenu

I would like to create a context menu (long press on a textview) that will show a list of options.
Difference from regular context menu will be, that the use is different: user will long click on the textview, menu will popup, user will not release finger, point to the menu item, release finger. This will fire the action.

Any idea how ot do it?>Can you refer me to an example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unless you have a very specific use case, I'd recommend against changing how the user expects a context menu to behave, and stay with the default behaviour. It can lead to quite a jarring user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fully achieve it. But this might help you. You can create a context menu as shown [here](http://www.anddev.org/creating_a_contextmenu_on_a_listview-t2438.html).

Hope this helps.